# macOS Big Sur shows update notifications, but won't install older versions of apps

Tags: macos, software-update, mac-appstore

I have an older MacBookPro (11,3) running Big Sur, the latest supported version of macOS on this machine. My problem is that I am constantly seeing notifications informing me of available updates.

When I actually open App Store and try to update, say, Numbers, I get a pop-up telling me that the current version requires macOS 13.5 and offering to download the latest supported version. I click download. The popup disappears and reappears half a second later with the same text. So I click again and the same thing happens. Several cycles later, I am back where I started. See below.

[image]

Is it possible that Apple no longer provides the relevant older versions of its software?

Is there some way to at least tell App Store to quit bugging me about these specific apps? I know that I can disable notifications for App Store entirely, but I have several other apps that update just fine.

Comment: Do you already have the latest supported version?  It's likely a bug, as Apple probably doesn't put too much effort into testing older hardware.

Comment: Apparently not. I have 10.3.5, but Google turns up forum posts where people are running 11.x on Catalina, which is the version before Big Sur.